# Data Preprocessing steps with pandas and numpy not working

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, numpy, anaconda, data-science

I am having trouble following [this Tutorial regarding Markov Chains in Python.](https://towardsdatascience.com/marketing-channel-attribution-with-markov-chains-in-python-part-2-the-complete-walkthrough-733c65b23323)

As advised, I have installed Anaconda to be used with vscode. When following the tutorial I get an Error message when I try to run this code:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as pd
from collections import defaultdict

df = pd.read_csv('attribution data.csv')
df = df.sort_values(['cookie', 'time'],
                    ascending=[False, True])
df['visit_order'] = df.groupby('cookie').cumcount() + 1
df_paths = df.groupby('cookie')['channel'].aggregate(
    lambda x: x.unique().tolist()).reset_index()
    
df_last_interaction = df.drop_duplicates('cookie', keep='last')[['cookie', 'conversion']]
df_paths = pd.merge(df_paths, df_last_interaction, how='left', on='cookie')

df_paths['path'] = np.where(
    df_paths['conversion'] == 0,
    ['Start'] + df_paths['channel'] + ['Null'],
    ['Start'] + df_paths['channel'] + ['Conversion'])

df_paths = df_paths[['cookie', 'path']]
```

Running it as is I get the following Error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "e:\[my folder path]\tempCodeRunnerFile.py", line 5, in <module>
    df = pd.read_csv('attribution data.csv')
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\numpy\__init__.py", line 219, in __getattr__
    raise AttributeError("module {!r} has no attribute "
AttributeError: module 'numpy' has no attribute 'read_csv'
```

I then tried to change the `import numpy as pd` to `import numpy as np`, as I couldn't really find anything with the first version. That results in the following Error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\ops\array_ops.py", line 149, in na_arithmetic_op
    result = expressions.evaluate(op, str_rep, left, right)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\computation\expressions.py", line 208, in evaluate
    return _evaluate(op, op_str, a, b)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\computation\expressions.py", line 121, in _evaluate_numexpr
    result = _evaluate_standard(op, op_str, a, b)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\computation\expressions.py", line 70, in _evaluate_standard
    return op(a, b)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\ops\roperator.py", line 9, in radd
    return right + left
TypeError: can only concatenate str (not "list") to str

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "e:\[my folder path]\tempCodeRunnerFile.py", line 17, in <module>
    ['Start'] + df_paths['channel'] + ['Null'],
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\ops\common.py", line 64, in new_method
    return method(self, other)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\ops\__init__.py", line 503, in wrapper
    result = arithmetic_op(lvalues, rvalues, op, str_rep)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\ops\array_ops.py", line 197, in arithmetic_op
    res_values = na_arithmetic_op(lvalues, rvalues, op, str_rep)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\ops\array_ops.py", line 151, in na_arithmetic_op
    result = masked_arith_op(left, right, op)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\ops\array_ops.py", line 98, in masked_arith_op
    raise TypeError(type(y))
TypeError: <class 'list'>
```

I have never worked with Data Science before and would love to get at least this part running, as the result can be used in R or python for the following steps. I apologize for my cluelessness.

Comment: Evaluate this line by itself `['Start'] + df_paths['channel'] + ['Null']`. I bet it'll work as `'Start' + df_paths['channel'] + 'Null'`.

Comment: @PaulH I just changed it as you suggested to no avail, sadly. `  File "e:\[my folder path]TechnicalTask\test.py", line 17, in <module> 'Start' + df_paths['channel'] + 'Null'` with the error message: `TypeError: can only concatenate str (not "list") to str`. At least it changed from `tempCodeRunnerFile.py` to my actual python file (`test.py`)

Comment: make this example runnable. i'm not quite sure what you're trying to do yet

Answer (score 1):

FIrst, it is correct,

`import numpy as pd`

it should be

`import numpy as np`

Then, try:

```
df_paths['path'] = np.where( df_paths['conversion'] == 0,
['Start, '] + df_paths['channel'].apply(', '.join) + [', Null'],
['Start, '] + df_paths['channel'].apply(', '.join) + [', Conversion'])


df_paths['path'] = df_paths['path'].str.split(', ')

df_paths = df_paths[['cookie', 'path']]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
df_paths['path'] = np.where( df_paths['conversion'] == 0,
['Start, '] + df_paths['channel'].apply(lambda row: [str(val) for val in row]).apply(', '.join) + [', Null'],
['Start, '] + df_paths['channel'].apply(lambda row: [str(val) for val in row]).apply(', '.join) + [', Conversion'])
```

Answer (score -1):

You can try this:

```py
def f(c, p):
    if c == 0:
        return ['Start']+ p + ['Null']
    else: 
        return ['Start'] + p + ['Conversion']
     
df_paths['path'] = df_paths.apply(lambda x: f(x['conversion'], x['channel']), axis = 1)
df_paths.head()
```